# QGIS 2.16.2 installation on Windows: 'Extract: error writing to file_flapack.pyd'

Tags: qgis, installation, windows

I encountered an error while installing QGIS 2.16.2 Nodebo (see below)
and I don't know how to address this problem.

[image: error]

Comment: Can you add some more details please? Such as: Did you run the installer as administrator? Are you running the correct 32/64-bit installer? And any other relevant details =)

Comment: I already run it as administrator and I am using 64-bit installer. I also tested the installer to my friend's laptop and it worked but in my laptop it do not work. I also tried downloading another installer but still do not work.

Comment: Problem seems to lie with your laptop. Are you running the installer from inside your laptop (i.e. not from a USB or online)?

Comment: yes, I am running it inside my laptop

Comment: What is the path you are installing it to? Are you using the default path: `C:/Program Files/`?

Answer (score 1):

Check your temporary directory:

```
cmd.exe
echo %TMP%
```

In my case, it pointed a partition without enough space for the installer to complete the extraction. If it's your case, you can try to clean up that partition or change the temporary directory used by the installer by changing the following environnement variables (control panel, system, advanced system settings, environment variables):

```
TEMP
TMP
```